# grails use offset/max and pagination with getAll?

Tags: grails, pagination

I have a list of integer representing ids.

I want to use getAll to retreive and return all instances to GSP and I would like also to use pagination (offset, max).

How can I do that

```
MyClass.getAll([1, 2, 3,...])
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `findAllBy*` or drill down using an HQL with `executeQuery`. I think the former approach will be simpler since only `ids` are involved.

```
MyClass.findAllByIdInList([1, 2, 3, ....]*.toLong(), [max: 5, offset: 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

As dmahapatro pointed out you can also use executeQuery. This gives you a lot of control of the query to run and the params to pass in.

```
def users = User.executeQuery("from User u where u.id IN (1,2,3)",[max:2,offset:0])
```